# Why does this rule give me 404 on sitemap.xml?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I use seo framework to generate sitemap.xml. Adding below rule in my nginx confix throws 404 error. How can I fix this?

```
location ~* \.(xml|xsl)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control “no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0”;
    expires -1;
}
```

Comment: "How can I fix this?" Dont add your rule

Comment: This rule is for static files. Is the sitemap.xml static - i.e. - does it really exist in the document root ? If it's dynamic - remove it, it should be processes via your dynamic framework.

Comment: Since its dynamic how can I apply the rule to it so that it wont get cached? Thank you for helping out.